# Creating a negative lookahead in a pgrep/pkill command within a complicated unix command

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep, regex-lookarounds

I'm writing a daemon that will log in to other machines to confirm that a service is running and also start, stop, or kill it. Because of this, the unix commands get a little long and obfuscated.

The basic shape of the commands that are forming are like:

```
bash -c 'ssh -p 22 user@host.domain.com pgrep -fl "APP.*APP_id=12345"'
```

Where APP is the name of the remote executable and APP_id is a parameter passed to the application when started.

The executable running on the remote side will be started with something like:

```
/path/to/APP configs/config.xml -v APP_id=12345 APP_port=2345 APP_priority=7
```

The exit status of this command is used to determine if the remote service is running or was successfully started or killed.

The problem I'm having is that when testing on my local machine, ssh connects to the local machine to make things easier, but pgrep called this way will also identify the ssh command that the server is running to do the check.

For example, pgrep may return:

```
26308 ./APP configs/config.xml APP_id=128bb8da-9a0b-474b-a0de-528c9edfc0a5 APP_nodeType=all APP_exportPort=6500 APP_clientPriority=11
27915 ssh -p 22 user@localhost pgrep -fl APP.*APP_id=128bb8da-9a0b-474b-a0de-528c9edfc0a5
```

So the logical next step was to change the pgrep pattern to exclude 'ssh', but this seems impossible because pgrep does not seem to be compiled with a PCRE version that allows lookaheads, for example:

```
bash -c -'ssh -p 22 user@localhost preg -fl "\(?!ssh\).*APP.*APP_id=12345"
```

This will throw a regex error, so as a workaround I was using grep:

```
bash -c 'ssh -p 22 user@host.domain.com pgrep -fl "APP.*APP_id=12345" \\| grep -v ssh'
```

This works well for querying with pgrep even though it's a workaround.  However, the next step using pkill doesn't work because there's no opportunity for grep to be effective:

```
bash -c 'ssh -p 22 user@host.domain.com pkill -f "APP.*APP_id=12345"'
```

Doesn't work well because pkill also kills the ssh connection which causes the exit status to be bad. So, I'm back to modifying my pgrep/pkill pattern and not having much luck.

This environment can be simulated with something simple on a local machine that can ssh to itself without a password (in this case, APP would be 'watch'):

```
watch echo APP_id=12345
```

Here is the question simply put: **How do I match 'APP' but not 'ssh user@host APP' in pgrep?**

Comment: It might be helpful if you include the process list to better understand the pattern needed.

Comment: You might want to  use [systemd user instance](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User) to let *systemd* manage your services.

Comment: @JürgenHötzel the remote machines are cloud instances... it would be possible to install the service I'm writing for systemd, but that's not quite the question... I'm wondering if I'm missing some regex syntax I'm not aware of.

Comment: @l'L'l I updated the question to include some pgrep output, which illustrates that the pgrep command is matching itself because it is wrapped by ssh

Comment: Using the `-o` option should identify the oldest running process that pgrep matches, and only return that.

Comment: I had tried that too, but it will cause a false positive if the service is not running... IE the oldest running process in that case is the ssh command.

Comment: True, although there are multiple other ways to handle that (eg. setting up a pidfile, match against arguments `-f`, piping an additional grep `-v` "ssh", etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a workaround, but does the job:

```
bash -c 'ssh -p 22 user@host.domain.com pgrep -fl "^[^\s]*APP.*APP_id=12345"'
```

...which only matches commands that have no space before the application name.  This isn't entirely complete, because it's possible that the path to the executable may contain a directory with spaces, but without lookaround syntax I haven't thought of another way to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

really old q but!

export VAR="agent.py"; pkill -f .*my$VAR;

Comment: It is unclear why you think this is an answer to the question at the top of this page. Did you answer the wrong question by mistake?